# I can't realise delegate pattern

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, delegates

Beginner in SWIFT

I have 2 ViewController  and want to show in secondVC(some Label) what I wrote in firstVC(some textfield) I checked similar topics but found nothing, there is something similar with storyboard, but I don't know storyboard.

my firstVC:

```
protocol DataDelegate {
    func getWord(word:String)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
     
    let mainView = MainView()
    var delegate: DataDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view = mainView
        addTargets()
    }

    func addTargets() {
        mainView.startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startGame), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func startGame() {
        
        guard mainView.wordTf.text!.count > 7 else {
            print("Slishkom korotkoe slovo")
            return
        }
        
        let vc = GameViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        delegate?.getWord(word: mainView.wordTf.text!)
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

my secondVC:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let gameView = GameView()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view = gameView
        addTargets()
    }
    
    func addTargets() {
       
        gameView.backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissSelf), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissSelf() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        

    }

}

extension GameViewController: DataDelegate {
    func getWord(word: String) {
        gameView.bigWord.text = word
    }
    
    
}
```

I didn't find anything similar, pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly do NOT want to use protocol/delegate pattern for this...

In general, you want to *pass data* to your presented controller (your `GameViewController`) when you create it, and then present it.

Add a property to your `GameViewController` to *receive* the data (a string, in this case):

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var gameWord: String = ""

    // all the rest of your code

}
```

Then, when you tap a button in `MainViewController` to call `startGame()`:

```
@objc func startGame() {
    
    guard theWord = mainView.wordTf.text, theWord.count > 7 else {
        print("Slishkom korotkoe slovo")
        return
    }
    
    let vc = GameViewController()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

    // "pass" the data here
    vc.gameWord = theWord

    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

You now have the text entered into `wordTf` set as `gameWord` in your game view controller, and you can use it however you want.

Comment: now im confused , when I should use protocol/delegate pattern...

Comment: protocol/delegate pattern is useful when you have a class that **may** need to communicate with another class -- most commonly, to inform a "parent" that something has happened. Think about table view telling its parent (its `delegate`) that a row was selected. To learn about it, head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `when I should use protocol/delegate pattern` ... many, many discussions, tutorials, examples, etc.

Comment: @jiokotok In your original question you have A creating B as well as A giving B data. Definitely not a use for a delegate pattern. A typical use for a delegate pattern is when B can be created by X, Y, or Z, and B needs to get info from its creator at various times. The delegate pattern allows B to get the data when it needs it without knowing specifically who created it.